# Global variable Issues with different functions (using Python)

Tags: python, list, global-variables

I am trying to create a program that allows me to use my list 'users' in a different function in the program. 
I have tried parameters, declaring it 'global' (although I've been told it's bad practice to do that) and I've tried researching 'class' and implementing it all to no avail. I have also tried putting users into a text file and then reading from it but it's a nuisance as I need it to be in a list. 
Here is my code:

```
def register():
    global username
    username = raw_input("Enter a username: ").lower()
    firstName = raw_input("Enter your first name: ").lower()
    surname = raw_input("Enter your surname: ").lower()
    age = raw_input("Enter your age: ")
    yearGroup = raw_input("Enter your year group: ")
    users =[[firstName, surname, age, yearGroup]] 

def resultsFunction(): 
    score = 5
    results = [[score, username]]
    results.extend(users)
```

I have tried:

```
def register():
    global username
    username = raw_input("Enter a username: ").lower()
    firstName = raw_input("Enter your first name: ").lower()
    surname = raw_input("Enter your surname: ").lower()
    age = raw_input("Enter your age: ")
    yearGroup = raw_input("Enter your year group: ")
```

> ```
>   global users
> ```

```
    users =[[firstName, surname, age, yearGroup]]
```

It throws up the error:

```
    results.extend(userDetails)
NameError: global name 'userDetails' is not defined
```

The strange thing is, after declaring username 'global' (yes, I know I shouldn't, but it worked), I was able to use the username in the function but when I tried it with the other variables, e.g firstName so I could try to create the list simply in the 'resultsFunction' it wouldn't work.

The register function does not get run all the time if the user decides not to register but I can't change that as I do not want the user to have to always put in their details.

I am so confused and have tried everything I know. I came here as a last resort so I hope that someone can help and that maybe this question can help others having the same difficulties with the local and global variables scopes.

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Whoops, sorry. I thought the example code contained all you needed to understand it. Terribly sorry but I don't have any other code that is relevant to this question.

Comment: Put `global username` as the first line of your `register()` function, *inside* the function, then try again.

Comment: @cdarkeThank you for your help in improving my question. I have edited it. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Did you see my previous comment?  I think it should work now.  However I strongly recommend that you pass parameters and return results rather than using globals.

Comment: @cdarke I think you misunderstood my question. The username part works fine but its the users list part that's the problem. I have also replied to the answer below this as to what the result of it is which I think is similar to what you suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `global users` inside the function to change values in the `users` variable. Otherwise you can only read it but not change the value inside it.

```
lis = []
def a():
    lis = [1,2]
a()
print(lis)
```

will print `[]`

where as :

```
lis = []
def a():
    global lis
    lis = [1,2]
a()
print(lis)
```

will print `[1,2]`

With reference to your program as per my understanding.. this might help..

```
username = ''
user = []
def register():
    global username
    global users
    username = input("Enter a username: ").lower()
    firstName = input("Enter your first name: ").lower()
    surname = input("Enter your surname: ").lower()
    age = input("Enter your age: ")
    yearGroup = input("Enter your year group: ")
    users =[[firstName, surname, age, yearGroup]]
def resultsFunction(): 
    score = 5
    results = [[score, username]]
    results.extend(users)
    print(results)
register()
resultsFunction()
```

will output :-

```
Enter a username: Foo
Enter your first name: Bar
Enter your surname: Baz
Enter your age: 00
Enter your year group: 00
[[5, 'foo'], ['bar', 'baz', '00', '00']]
```

Comment: I have just tried this. It doesn't throw up the error anymore but when I print `results = [[score, username]]
 results.extend(users)
 print results` it only prints the score and userEntry: `[['4', 'mary14']]`

Comment: I could not understand your program clearly, but this is my attempt to help. Please let know if this is of any help to you.

Comment: If you want Output in `[5, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', '00', '00']` this format then you can replace `[[...]]` in `users` and `results` to `[...]`.This format is should get you going

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid. It's working now! I forgot to actually go through the register function again haha. You have helped me so much! Thank you!!